# Accessing Dynamically created variables inside function

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I've been trying to solve this for days so hopefully someone knows the answer.

At the top of my script I dynamically set a variable like so:
`$p_id = $_GET['p_id'];`

I have then attempted to pass this variable to the following function in three different ways without any luck.

1)

```
public function Insert_Update($uid,$update,$uploads,**$p_id**) 
{
.....        

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, uid_fk, poster_id,ip,created,uploads) VALUES ('$update', '$uid',
**'$p_id'**, '$ip','$time','$uploads')") or die(mysql_error());....
```

Interestingly, this approach works for the variable if I change the order of the arguments to `($p_id,$uid,$update,$uploads)`, however the other three variables become invisible to the function.

2)

```
public function Insert_Update($uid,$update,$uploads) 
{...

     // ... global **$p_id**;

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, uid_fk, poster_id,ip,created,uploads) VALUES ('$update', '$uid',
        **'$p_id'**, '$ip','$time','$uploads')") or die(mysql_error());....
```

3)

```
public function Insert_Update($uid,$update,$uploads) 
{
     ....
      //  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, uid_fk, poster_id,ip,created,uploads) VALUES ('$update', '$uid',
     '".$_REQUEST[**'p_id'**]."', '$ip','$time','$uploads')") or die(mysql_error());...
```

No matter what approach I try the function never sees the variable. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please wrap code appropriately. It will help those helping you read and differentiate code.

Comment: Stop.  using.  `mysql_query`.  It's been obsolete for years now.  Check out PDO and/or mysqli.

Comment: Have you ensured that, in example 1, `$uid`, `$update` and `$uploads` are correct? If somethings broken with those variables, then `$p_id` won't be parsed, but it would explain why it's parsed when placed as the first variable.

Comment: Spiritfyre you're a genious! Haha something was wrong with the $uploads variable. Before I hadn't tried removing them one by one but once I did it works. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than just using `$p_id = $_GET['p_id'];`, ensure that `$_GET['p_id']` has a value first. Try the following code:

```
$p_id = isset($_GET['p_id'])? $_GET['p_id'] : "some default value";
```

Or, if you want to throw an error if the variable isn't set, try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['p_id']))
{
    $p_id = $_GET['p_id'];
}
else
{
    echo "Please set 'p_id' and try again.";
    exit();
}
```

Also, as a general rule of thumb, avoid using the same variable name in a function as defined outside it, if possible. E.g. in your function try naming it `$pid` instead of `$p_id`, because that's the variable used outside your function as well.

**EDIT**
Rather than define `$p_id` as a constant, then add it to the `$GLOBALS` array, then pass it in, just ensure that `$p_id` is set, then pass it in. For example:

```
$p_id = isset($_GET['p_id'])? $_GET['p_id'] : 2;

public function Insert_Update($uid,$update,$uploads,$pid) 
{
.....        

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (message, uid_fk, poster_id,ip,created,uploads) VALUES ('$update', '$uid',
'$pid', '$ip','$time','$uploads')") or die(mysql_error());....
}

Insert_Update(1, "some text", "some file", $p_id);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers...I really appreciate it. I don't think there is a problem with the $uid, $update, and $uploads variables because when I set $p_id to a constant within the function everything is fine. Like so

Comment: Try setting it as a constant _outside of_ the function, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry like so :public function Insert_Update($uid,$update,$uploads) 
 {
         
 $update=mysql_real_escape_string($update);
        $time=time();
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
           $p_id = 2

Comment: Rather than redefine `$p_id` _inside_ your function, ensure it's defined *_before_* you pass it to your function.

Comment: I did try setting it as a constant outside the function and had some success when I used $GLOBALS to pass the value into the function, however once I made the variable dynamic again this no longer worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are just wasting memory by creating a new variable.

`$_GET['p_id']` is accessible in ANY scope, so it is automatically visible wherever you are accessing it. This is much easier than trying to pass a regular variable into it.

Comment: Agree, but if the OP is using a function, maybe `$p_id` won't always be taken from `$_GET['p_id']`? That's the purpose of a function. Versatility.

Comment: @Spiritfyre Then it would make more sense to pass in `$p_id`. Globals feel messy IMHO

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I completely agree. Globals have there place, but there place is rare. Passing variables in is a much better way to go, because it doesn't rely on a variable already existing, it leaves it open and versatile for both direct input, or passed variables.

Comment: I did attempt $_GET['p_id'] inside the function and that was also not seen by the function, which was frustrating because I thought for sure that that would work.